# How to replace all line and more?

Tags: php, replace

now my problem is replace all line from # and from /* to */(for comments).
I have code:

```
<span>#include <a_samp><br />#define NUMBER 5<br />/* Long Comment */ new var[128]; format(var, sizeof(var), "kažkas %s %f", "Stuneris", 1589.0587); SendClientMessage(playerid, 0xFFFFFFFF, var);</span>
```

and I want to replace from `#` all **line** to `<h1>#...(line)</h1>` and from `/*` to `*/` to `<h3>/* Long Comment */</h3>`

I tired `preg_replace('/(/*(?!,)[^"]+*/)/i', '<h3>$1</h3>', $text);`, but it show warning `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '*' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pawn.php on line 18`

I know, I need preg_replace, but how combination of search?

Comment: hard time understanding what exactly you want. Would be helpful if you showed the complete string as you want it to look after the regex

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do in general, but you're getting that `preg_replace` error because the regex parser recognizes the `/` before the `*` as the closing delimiter for the entire regex. You need to use a different delimiter for the expression.

Comment: You need to escape the `/` in your regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to escape the special characters in you regexp

```
preg_replace('/(\/\*(?!,)[^"]+\*\/)/i', '<h3>$1</h3>', $text);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/CbSoMUpY)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to try the following:

```
preg_replace('/(\/\*(?!,)[^"]+\*\/)/i', '<h3>$1</h3>', $text);
```

- is a special character in all cases ( http://www.regular-expressions.info/ ) . / is additionally "special" here because you're also using it as your delimiter.